# VB.Net Upgrade Stored Procedure Call to Oracle Database moRs.Open(moCmd)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, oracle

I have a program that was written in VB6 and we are trying to convert to VB.Net. When calling stored procedures in Microsoft SQL 2012 and in Oracle using this .Open() method, Microsoft SQL executes fine while Oracle does not. Here is a snippet of code:

```
Private moRs As ADORecordSetHelper =  New ADORecordSetHelper("")       
Private moCmd As DbCommand 'where moCmd has the procedure call and parameters
   moRs.Open(moCmd)
```

Here is the definition of .Open()

```
Public Sub Open(command As System.Data.Common.DbCommand)         
   Member of UpgradeHelpers.DB.ADO.ADORecordSetHelper
```

This all works for Microsoft SQL just not with Oracle. I found execute moCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() will work execute the stored procedure, but I need to get the recordset in certain instances as a result.

Is there a way to use moRs.Open(moCmd) for both Microsoft and Oracle? If not, how could I accomplish the same task of getting back the recordsets?

**UPDATE:** I have figured out that the .Open() method uses Execute Reader which is working fine for the Microsoft SQL that strictly returns a recordset. The Oracle stored procedure is inserting rows and returning values from the procedure. Doing an Execute NonQuery on the same object (moCmd) executes just fine, but all I am able to get from this method is the number of rows affected and not the other information that I need. Thoughts on why the Execture Reader doesn't work? My search says that it should work for all types of SQL; insert, delete, update, etc.

Comment: Um well personally I'd get rid of the data layer all together and use .net. Going to cause nothing but trouble this. This might help you though, http://www.vbtonet.com/legacy-data-access-to-net/adodb-helpers/

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I agree. Really the program should just be rewritten, but there isn't time for that. Actually the link you sent me is the application that I used to do the upgrade from VB6 to .Net. Hasn't helped me much.

Comment: Isn't time for it... I have a canned response for that one. "There's never enough time to do it right, but always enough time to do it again". Does that code work with straight sql, if so may be exec my_sp... would do the job.